# Naming convention for C# class that provides layer of redirection

Tags: c#, design-patterns, oop

I have a class whose sole purpose is to decide, based on a setting, whether to call A) a business layer using a WCF service first or B) the business layer directly.

What is the naming convention for a class the is just a redirector. I was thinking either using "Wrapper" or "Controller" in the class name.

Comment: I like `Controller` or `CallController` personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used **façade** for classes like this - though I prefer to just let the business layer itself handle the decision when possible.

Comment: LOL, I had *no* idea about that.  From now on, all my code will be multilingual just to confuse other devs!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some other good choices.

- Proxy
- Facade
- Surrogate
- Agent

Come up with a few good candidates and start plugging them into your favorite thesaurus to get alternate ideas.

Comment: Typically I have also used Proxy for this type of class

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply call it `Redirector`? Good description of what it does, and you don't use overused terms like "Wrapper" or "Controller".

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest level, what you are describing is a proxy to your business layer.

As it is directing the dispatch of your remote method invocation, you could call it a dispatcher or director.  However, I would expcet something called 'dispatcher' to actually send something to a destination (such as a work unit, or piece of data) and not block waiting for it to complete.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds somewhat like a [Service Locator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) to me.

That being said, I can't help wanting to name it [The Decider](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/George_W._Bush).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use the term *facade*.